# Setting timer for central locking for forgetful owners

Tags: locks, saab

Is it technically possible to set a timer for central locking so that it locks after 5 minutes, say, after the engine has been turned off? This is to help if you forget to lock your car at night.

Details of any other known solutions are also gratefully received.

Comment: Some cars do this, yes. Most do not-the risk of course is that you leave your keys in the car and they get locked in

Comment: I am looking for a modification.  How would you go about getting this done?

Comment: This might sound silly, but I'd recommend asking over on electronics.stackexchange.com rather than here

Answer (score 1):

An auto-electrician who installs alarms and remote unlocks would probably be able to help.

The cars that do this already generally require you take the key out, too. I know high-end Subarus will re-lock a car within a minute or so if you don't open the door.

Comment: Thanks. I will ask one of those.  The alternative I suppose is just for the car to beep annoyingly every minute or two that but might drive someone mad :)